# (SQL, VB.NET) How Do I select multiple values from one row and assign them to variables?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb, vb.net-2010

I am writing a SELECT query to use in my project. So far, I have

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim StudentID, GradeID, SubjectID As Integer
    Dim YourGrade(4), YourSubject(4) As String
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =H:\Year 13 Computer Science\Project\Usernames and Passwords.accdb"


        conn.Open()
        Dim sql = "Select * From Grades where StudentID =" & CurrentID
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read
            StudentID = dr("StudentID")
            GradeID = dr("GradeID")
            SubjectID = dr("SubjectID")
        End While
```

My issue is that I need to be able to have a dynamic number of SubjectIDs and GradeIDs to be selected, in case a student is taking more or fewer subjects than the normal three.

My Query produces:

```
StudentID   GradeID SubjectID
1              2        1
1              4        13
1              3        19
```

the CurrentID is "1" for the purposes of this.

Each GradeID and SubjectID corresponds to values in other tables which I can work on later.

I need to be able to have each of those three Grade IDs in a separate value, an array could be used but I don't know how to code it. I attempted it earlier as shown by the "YourGrade(4), YourSubject(4)".

I intend to use the data to fill out a Data Grid.

Comment: If you want to use the data for a data grid, why not just use a date adapter to fill a dataset or a data table?

Comment: My issue isn't how to present the data, I have other functioning datagrids within my program. If you read the question you'll see that my data from the table is a series of numbers which wouldn't convey any information to a user and therefore I need other functions before I can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a domain object for "Student" and then load the records into a list of Student Objects.

I don't know VB.net, but the equivalent Domain object in C# would look like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
}
```

And then the code to loop through the dataReader and populate the list:

```
List<Student> results = new List<Student>();

while (dr.Read())
{
    results.Add(new Student()
    {
         StudentId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["StudentID"]),
         GradeId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["GradeId"]),
         SubjectId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SubjectId"])
    });
}
```

-- Edit 2/2/2017 --

Turns out there are free converters on the web.  These are the VB.net equivalents to the snippets above.

Class:

```
Public Class Student
    Public Property StudentId() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_StudentId
        End Get
        Set
            m_StudentId = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_StudentId As Integer
    Public Property GradeId() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_GradeId
        End Get
        Set
            m_GradeId = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_GradeId As Integer
    Public Property SubjectId() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_SubjectId
        End Get
        Set
            m_SubjectId = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_SubjectId As Integer
End Class
```

Database Code:

Dim results As New List(Of Student)()

```
While dr.Read()
    results.Add(New Student() With { _
        Key .StudentId = Convert.ToInt32(dr("StudentID")), _
        Key .GradeId = Convert.ToInt32(dr("GradeId")), _
        Key .SubjectId = Convert.ToInt32(dr("SubjectId")) _
    })
End While
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I don't know C# but I have something to work with now.

Comment: Turns out there are free converters online...  I posted the VB.net versions of the code.  It looks like Greek to me, but hopefully you find it helpful.

Comment: Free converters? Now I feel stupid, haha. I'll try this next time I get access to my project, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging, found out that to fill out a datagrid in the way I was attempting to, the simplest way is to use an INNER JOIN SQL statement. In SQL the query is:

```
    SELECT Students.FirstName, Students.LastName, Subjects.SubjectName,    GradeVals.Grade
FROM GradeVals INNER JOIN (Students INNER JOIN (Subjects INNER JOIN Grades ON Subjects.SubjectID = Grades.SubjectID) ON Students.StudentID = Grades.StudentID) ON GradeVals.GradeID = Grades.GradeID;
```

That's using my Table names and such as.